# What is note_ind:ncol(dataset) mean in R?

Tags: r

I have this line of code but I don't know what it means especially the note_ind part.

```
apply(mydat[,-c(1,2,3,note_ind:ncol(dataset))],c(1,2),as.numeric)
```

Comment: This code snippet is a bit short to understand it; my guess is that `note_ind` is an index for the dataframe or matrix `mydat`.

Answer (score 0):

The notation `x:y` is used to create numeric vector sequences where each element is the previous element incremented by 1. It is shorthand for `seq(x, y, by = 1). It is most commonly used for integer sequences, but it works on doubles also.

```
1:10
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1.1:10.1
[1]  1.1  2.1  3.1  4.1  5.1  6.1  7.1  8.1  9.1 10.1
1.5:10.2  # sequence stops after 9.5 because 10.2 < 9.5 + 1 - seq() behaves the same way
[1] 1.5 2.5 3.5 4.5 5.5 6.5 7.5 8.5 9.5
```

Presumably `note_ind` is an integer value from somewhere else in your code. `ncol(data.set)` is the number of columns, so `note_ind:ncol(dataset)` generates a seqence between those two values, incrementing by 1 for each element.